# What is the meaning of "./has!dom-addeventlistener?:./aspect" in a dependency?

Tags: javascript, dojo, requirejs

I am using [dojo toolkit](https://github.com/dojo/dojo) in a project and it uses require.js to load scripts. 
In [on.js](https://github.com/dojo/dojo/blob/master/on.js), it loads the following scripts:

```
define(["./has!dom-addeventlistener?:./aspect", "./_base/kernel", "./sniff"], function(aspect, dojo, has){
```

When using on.js I get not found error:

```
Uncaught Error: 
  Missing: http://localhost:8585/dom-addeventlistener?:./aspect.js
```

Im wondering what does the `./has!dom-addeventlistener?:./aspect` notation do, and if I remove it what the potential impacts could be. It seems to work when i just do `./aspect` instead.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the `dojo/has` module as a plugin it behaves like a ternary operator:

> The conditional (ternary) operator is the only JavaScript operator that takes three operands. This operator is frequently used as a shortcut for the if statement.

```
condition ? expr1 : expr2
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Best explained by the follow example from the reference:

```
require(["dojo/has", "dojo/has!touch?dojo/touch:dojo/mouse", "dojo/dom", "dojo/domReady!"],
    function(has, hid, dom){
        if(has("touch")){
            dom.byId("output").innerHTML = 
                "You have a touch capable device and so I loaded <code>dojo/touch</code>.";
        } else {
            dom.byId("output").innerHTML =
                "You do not have a touch capable device and so I loaded <code>dojo/mouse</code>.";
        }
    }
);
```

https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/has.html

The important bit: `dojo/has!touch?dojo/touch:dojo/mouse` What happens here is, the `dojo/has` module is loaded and checks for `touch` (if you have a touch capable device), if test is ok and it's found, it's loads `dojo/touch`. If not it loads `dojo/mouse`.

In your case: `./has!dom-addeventlistener?:./aspect"`,  `dojo/has` tests for the availability of the DOM's addEventListener method. If it's found it loads nothing, because the part between `?` and `:` is ommited. If it's not found it loads `dojo/aspect`.

Code like that is generally used if a module can also be run on the serverside where there is no DOM like in the browser. I'de say if you run in the browser only you can safely omit the entire requirement because every decent browser supports `addEventListener`

That said, the error that you're getting is that somehow `dojo/has` relative module path can't be loaded properly. It should also fail when loading `./aspect` but it doesn't which is weird. Make sure `dojo/has` is available, because removing the requirement is a workaround, not a solution to your actual problem.